# How to override a default windows cmd command? such as rebinding the notepad command to different program

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad

I have a habit of using the keyboard shortcuts

windows key + R and then typing the notepad command to write all my notes

the problem is i always end up with a bunch of notepads open that i have to close down later, talking to the likes of 50+ and have sometimes also lost a bunch of them cause of a crash or whatever

I've tried to change this habit by switching to better note taking programs but the habit of using that keyboard shortcut is just too ingrained into me due to years of using which makes it really hard to break

I've wanted to do it by rebinding the cmd notepad command to the different text editors but have no idea how to do this and if it's even possible

Comment: Does [windows - How to change the path for "run command" "notepad"? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930462/how-to-change-the-path-for-run-command-notepad) answer your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for posting that thread wasn't able to find it myself. But sadly it seems like the regedit path has changed since then
Did manage to find another App Paths path but i don't see Notepad in it "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths"

Comment: Why are you using `WOW6432Node`? Notepad is now 64-bit. That post mentions only  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`.

Comment: Why not create a shortcut to a multi-tabbed application, such as Notepad++, that requires just pressing a simple, easy to remember, key combo, such as Windows+N or Ctrl-Alt-N? Fewer key presses needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so here's a pretty good guide for what you want to do

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12617/how-to-replace-notepad-in-windows-7/

i'll summarize the basics below

---

first, you have to use a portable app version of your replacement app

next, (just in case) backup notepad.exe from the three locations that it resides

1. C:\Windows
2. C:\Windows\System32
3. C:\Windows\SysWOW64

now take ownership of and delete the three versions of notepad.exe

finally, copy the .exe of your replacement app to the three locations and rename it to notepad.exe

---

Afterthought edit: I get the feeling based on your question post that you're not looking for that answer, so I gave the above actual answer to your question.  But ultimately I totally agree with DrMoishe Pippik that the better solution to this would be to retrain yourself to use a different (and probably quicker/more efficient) set of keystrokes to open your new note-taking app.

Comment: Thanks it's a perfect solution and yeah I have tried replacing this habit with even shorter commands such as just "note" but it didn't manage to stick. with this solution i've actually been able to fix the problem completely.

Btw you can also use shortcuts instead of a portable app, my note taking program doesn't have a portable version but thankfully a shortcut worked